# Are nested queries standard in the SQL language?

Tags: sql

I know that for example MySQL implement nested query.

Is it a standard SQL feature, if such a standard exists?

Comment: you can read about subqueries in ANSI SQL-89 or may be in ANSI SQL-86

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there exists an SQL standard, first formalized by ANSI in 1986, and the revised in 1989, 1992, 1999, 2003. You can follow the links from the [Wikipedia page on SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

Here's a direct link to a copy of the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Subqueries (nested queries) are in it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I think by 'nested queries' you are referring to ['derived tables'](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/).

Support for derived tables were introduced into the SQL standard in SQL:1992. Prior to this all work had to be done within a single `SELECT..FROM`. This explains the existence of the rather odd `HAVING` clause, in order to do further filtering after `GROUP BY` summarization has been applied. [This possibly also explains why some SQL products seem better optimized for joins rather than subqueries and why to the average SO user all relational operators look like joins!] However, support for `HAVING` was not enough to allow SQL queries of arbitrary complexity, hence the need for derived tables.

Not only have derived tables made `HAVING` redundant, they finally made SQL relationally complete (by Codd's definition of that term), hence is a feature found in all modern SQL implementations.

Comment: @onedaywhen: As recently revealed by another question at SO, there are still exceptions and some (I guess new) products do not support all kinds of suqueries. [Greenplum](http://www.greenplum.com/) does no support (yet, as they say) correlated subqueries - although it's fine with uncorrelated ones.